# How do I add members to classes in a Class Diagram?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, keyboard-shortcuts, class-diagram

I just discovered the existence of Class Diagrams. At first i did think it was a very productive tool, but then i realized that the amount of time it takes to add a Property to a Class inside a Class Diagram with 4+ mouse clicks is simply embarrassing compared to actually writing the code ("Property foo as bar" in VB).

I am now looking for keyboard shortcuts to add all the possible members of a class :Properties, Fields, Methods and so on.

Comment: According to [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165370.aspx) there are no shortcuts for adding fields, properties, and methods.  You might find [productivity tools](http://george2giga.com/2014/10/06/resharper-vs-coderush-vs-justcode/) to me even more effective than the class designer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign your own keyboard shortcuts to many class diagram commands. Go to **Tools - Options**, **Environment - Keyboard**. Type *diagram* into **Show commands containing** field. You will see all available commands and you can define your shortcuts for them.

Comment: Too bad there is no keyboard shortcut defined by default... I had to make edits.